# Webmatrix - Passing variable from cshtml page to an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

I'm using Webmatrix to build my site which renders different fusioncharts when users click on different buttons, i.e. if they click on the "Europe" button, they get a graph of avg temperatures in Europe, if they click on US, US avg temperatures etc...

The cshtml page holds the session variable UserId after succesful login and if that user clicks a button if(ispost) code refreshes the whole cshtml page which then contains an updated graph.

On refresh, within the cshtml page there is an iframe whose source is a file called "Using_MS_SQL_Server.aspx" which in turn creates an xml file populated by the execution of a stored procedure on the ms sql database like so:

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(
    "EXEC ON_WEBSITE_SQL_DB.dbo.AVG_TEMPS_PER_CONTINENT "
     + AREA + ", " + USERID, conn);
```

As you can tell, there are two variables to plug into the stored proc: AREA and USERID...

Within the aspx.cs page's code I can easily call the USERID variable as it is a session variable using `MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();`.

How do I pass a variable with the value "EUROPE" from the cshtml page that the user is clicking to the aspx page for use in the stored procedure that is waiting for the AREA variable?

Comment: Can you pass it in the query string of the aspx url?

Comment: Your sample have SQL injection. Please try to remove it and update the question with safe code using parametrized queries.

Comment: @TGH: you nailed it... it works!!! brilliant, thank you!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: thanks will look into that - I thought I was safe as the aspx page renders the graph by calling another aspx page with code behind that renders the xml doc for the graph... is that still dangerous?

Comment: @TGH: how do i go about giving you reputation credit for the advice? Am new on the site, not sure how it works...

Comment: No worries. You can only give credit to answers, not comments. I am happy you got it working though

Comment: @TGH... cheers have a good evening

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - just tested the webpage with Mozillas "SQL inject me" add-on... it seems to have passed... if the add-on can be trusted...

Comment: Your call. It is just wrong way of writing SQL queries - to confirm you don't have injection issues you have to actually go through all your code to make sure the value you are concatenating into SQL statement *never* can come from external input. Using parametrized queries is easy and significantly simplify how you verify you don't have SQL injection issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways you'd be able to achieve that is either using session/cookies or the query string.

If the data you're passing isn't sensitive information, then just go with the query string. If it is sensitive, think about encrypting either a session or cookie value that you can decrypt on the `Page_Load` of the ASPX.